# Updating an array in MongoDB using Java driver

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB with the official Java driver (version 2.6.3). I have a MongoDB collection that contains shopping lists. A shopping list has the format

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4e2af1f43f8de96494d5271d"} ,
  "name" : "default" ,
  "items" : [ { "description" : "Cheese" , "quantity" : 1 , "unit" : "kg"} ,
              { "description" : "Water" , "quantity" : 3 , "unit" : "bottle"} ] }
```

Now I want to add a new item to the list with the `update()`method of `DBCollection`. But whatever I try it won't work although it's telling me

```
{ "updatedExisting" : true , "n" : 1 , "connectionId" : 63 , "err" :  null  , "ok" : 1.0}
```

My code does the following:

```
    BasicDBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    updateQuery.put( "name", "default" );

    BasicDBObject updateCommand = new BasicDBObject();
    updateCommand.put( "$push", new BasicDBObject( "items", newShoppingItem ) );
    WriteResult result = shoppingLists.update( updateQuery, updateCommand, true, true );
```

`newShoppingItem` is a `BasicDBObject` which contains the data for the new item. I also tried to create the `update()` parameters with `BasicDBObjectBuilder` and `JSON.parse()` but it makes no difference.

I also had a look at other posts, tried googleing, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!
Oliver

Comment: I ran that exact code with the MongoDB 2.5.3 driver and it worked fine.  Make sure you're looking in the right DB.

Comment: This was useful to me as a way of better understanding the somewhat obscure syntax in the Java driver for Mongo.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes, the above code works perfectly fine. I know now where my error was. I wanted to do it bullet-proof, so I thought it would be best to use save() on the DBCollection at the end and explicitly save the shopping list DBObject:

```
shoppingLists.save( shoppingList );
```

I now read in some other forum that the objects you retrieve from the database are then not synched with the database afterwards (sounds kind of logical to me now :) ). So I overwrote the changes myself every time. After removing the line above it worked :)

So one important rule: When you update your `DBCollection` – this is sent directly to the database! – don't save a `DBObject` that you queried before the update! It will overwrite your update!